# Python Library - __init__.py not importing .so file

Tags: python

I have a python library generated as a .so file

My directory structure looks like this:

```
myfolder
    library
        __init__.py
        _library.so
```

My **init**.py contains:

```
import _library as library
```

Now, when I am in myfolder and I do

```
import library
```

it says _library is not found. Why is this the case? How do i do this correctly?

If I navigate directly into library and i import _library it works

Comment: If you're using python3 that should be `from . import _library as library`

Comment: where do i actually do this line?

Comment: In your `__init__.py`?

Comment: Okay, but now when I try to use library from an external file it doesn't find it. I want to be able to use library in another file that isn't in the library folder

Comment: Okay, so within the __init__.py I am able to import library, But after that I cannot access the variable outside of that